# Django REST User Login

Tags: python, django, ajax, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am looking to login a user with a username and password in django. This is my code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user=user)
            return Response({'Message': "Success!"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"Message": "Invalid"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The authentication works fine, but when i go to login i get this:

```
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, 
not `rest_framework.request.Request`.
```

I am using the rest API, and my request looks like this

```
function login() {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password,
            }),
        };
        fetch("/users/login/", requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setStatus(data.Message))
    }
```

Would anyone know how to create a django request to log the user in? Thanks!

Comment: Add the urls.py and the whole login function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication

or

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication

instead

django authentication backends

and

login(request, user=user)

---

But better use jwt-token or OAuth